# Custom Module review in Magento 2

Tags: module, magento2, review

I am beginner learn Magento 2. I want customize module review. Can you tell me what to do that. Thanks!

Comment: That depend in what customisation you want in default review module.

Comment: I want add image, comment, like, dislike for review and show statistic stars in screen review. Can you guide me how to do it. Thanks